# How to install PyGTK for Python 2.7 on CentOS 6?

Tags: python, gtk, dependencies, centos

I am having a big problem installing PyGTK for Python 2.7 on CentOS 6.  The YUM on CentOS does not have Python 2.7 or any modules for it, so I had to build Python 2.7 from source.  But PyGTK has a very extensive dependency chain of Python modules!  I started getting a few of the modules' sources but it turned out to be an enormous rabbit hole.  How am I supposed to get all of these Python dependencies installed?  Do I literally have to manually download, compile, and install every single Python 2.7 module source in the dependency chain of PyGTK?  I think that this would take days, if not weeks, of manual effort.  Shouldn't there be an easier method for accomplishing this?  Has *anyone* ever done this before or is it even heard of for something like this to be done when the distribution doesn't come with the desired version of Python?

Answer (score 0):

PUIAS provides in his Computational repositories packages with Python 2.7 and also with PyGTK 2.16. Please Take look here: [PUIAS repositories](http://springdale.math.ias.edu/wiki/YumRepositories6)

Comment: So it's just a matter of using 3rd-party YUM repositories?

Comment: Short answer yes :). Long answer: yes if you don't have time for compiling custom packages and all dependencies. No, if you have time and mood to compile these packages (and dependencies). I think that PUIAS provides good packages, but I recommend to you use only the Computational repo to avoid mixing between the core Centos packages and PUIAS core packages.